# How possible is it to perform date ranges with date values of string data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am forced to work with a date value stored as strings.

For instance,

```
Fieldname: claimsDate
data Type: nvarchar
```

The values are stored in the format of `mmddyy`.

`E.G; 022413`.

I have managed to convert this to say 02/24/2013 using the following query.

```
select (left(claimsdate,2)  + '/' + substring(claimsdate,3,2) + '/' + case when cast(right(claimsdate,2) as int) >= 70 then '19' else '20' end + right(claimsdate,2)) claimsdate
from tblTable
```

The problem now is that we cannot perform a date range check with that code.

I have tried using it like this:

```
select (left(claimsdate,2)  + '/' + substring(claimsdate,3,2) + '/' + case when cast(right(claimsdate,2) as int) >= 70 then '19' else '20' end + right(claimsdate,2)) claimsdate
from tblTable 
where (left(claimsdate,2)  + '/' + substring(claimsdate,3,2) + '/' + case when cast(right(claimsdate,2) as int) >= 70 then '19' else '20' end + right(claimsdate,2))
between '03/01/2007' and '12/31/2007'
```

This didn't give me the range I was looking for. It just displayed dates arbitrarily.

Is it possible to manipuate the code to be used for date range checks?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: I edited the answer. This time I'm going to convert your string value into date with formate yyyy-mm-dd. This should work fine. Please remember using `@fromDate` and `@endDate` with yyyy-mm-dd format too.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this post. I am testing it now. Although we don't want it in that format but I will give it a go.

Didn't work.

Comment: Your original code is probably working. I *think* the issue might be from my db. I will examine it further to see what I can find.

I will close this thread. Thanks for all your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use datetime conversion in sql. This link show you full example http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

```
select (left(claimsdate,2)  + '/' + substring(claimsdate,3,2) + '/' + case when cast(right(claimsdate,2) as int) >= 70 then '19' else '20' end + right(claimsdate,2)) claimsdate
from tblTable 
where  cast(((case when cast(right(claimsdate,2) as int) >= 70 then '19' else '20' end + right(claimsdate,2) + '-' + left(claimsdate,2)  + '-' + substring(claimsdate,3,2))) as datetime)
between @fromDate and @endDate
```

With @fromDate and @endDate is datetime variable

I hope this will satisfy your need

Comment: Ok, just to clarify @Doan, My situation involves 2 solutions packaged into 1.

First, my date values are stored in the format of mmddyy. I don't see that in the link you posted.

Second, in addition to being in the format above, it is stored as string.

Can you show me where that is handled in that link?

Comment: `SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/16', 1) -- mm/dd/yy U.S.`

you can use this after convert your value into 'mm/dd/yy' format

Comment: You are solving a different problem from the one I posted.

I have data stored in the format of mmddyy. I wish to convert that to mm/dd/yyyy. My code above did that but problem is I can't perform date range validations with it.

Is there something that needs tweaking with my code or perhaps a different solution that will allow us to use it to perform date ranges?

Your solution is way off from what I am looking for.

Thanks though for trying.

Comment: Let me make it clarify. You have a column that stored the date in format mmddyy. You want to convert this to mm/dd/yyyy and use it in a where clause to find all the record have that column in between 2 given dates?

Comment: Correct! but let me add that is varchar. This is sql server.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please check if it solved your problem or not

Comment: I got an error that "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."